# Iterating over IntStream to print values

Tags: java, java-stream, java-threads

In the below example, I am using the field `number` in `IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(number -> new Thread(r).start());` even though it is not being used. Is there a way to rewrite it so that I do not have to use the unused number variable?

```java
    import javax.annotation.concurrent.NotThreadSafe;
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;
    
    public class LearnThreads {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            UnsafeThreadClass counter = new UnsafeThreadClass();
            Runnable r = () -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println(counter.getValue() + " : Thread - " +Thread.currentThread());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
            IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(number -> new Thread(r).start());
        }
    }
    
    
    @NotThreadSafe
    class UnsafeThreadClass {
        private int value;
    
        public synchronized int getValue() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            return value++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, not really. We need to pass along a `Consumer<Integer>` when using the `stream`-API.

Comment: At the moment, not if you want to use a lambda.  There is a proposal [JEP 302: Lambda Leftovers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/302) which would allow using underscore for unused lambda parameters, but it's not implemented yet as of Java 19.

Comment: You can opt for naming the parameter `ignore`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No; you must specify a name for the consumer's parameter, however why use a stream at all?

This is simpler and more readable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    new Thread(r).start();
}
```

If you must use a Stream, try `limit()` instead:

```
Stream.generate(() -> new Thread(r)).limit(10).forEach(Thread::start);
```

But there's an ugly producer in there.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian! Were you referring to the below supplier code as ugly producer? `() -> new Thread(r)`

Comment: Yes. It feels like `Thread(r)::new` should work, but no.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you can create a lightweight virtual `List` to a using static method [`Collections.nCopies()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)) (which behaves like a regular `List` but it's not baked by a real data structure, basically it's a wrapper around the provided reference and its memory footprint is tiny).

Here's how you can fire 10 `Runnable` tasks using Stream API and `nCopies()`:

```
Runnable r = // initializing the task
        
Collections.nCopies(10, r).stream().map(Thread::new).forEach(Thread::start);
```

The same can be done using without Streams using `Iterable.forEach()`:

```
Runnable r = // initializing the task

Collections.nCopies(10, r).forEach(task -> new Thread(task).start());
```